# How to change a log file name and type after export from cloudwatch to s3 using lambda function

Tags: lambda, export, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have an AWS lambda function(node.js) which exports logs from cloudwatch to s3.
I used a cloudwatchlogs api and createExportTask method. 
Also the function has a cloudwatch event trigger to export once a day.

It works well, but the problem is I don't know how to change the exported file name(000000) and type(gzip).
(I don't wanna use the way to subscribe the lambda function.)

Example path : cloudwatch-test/exportedlogs/069da15b-e6fb-4a11/logs/000000.gz

I'd really like to knwo how to change them, so if you know please let me know about this.

Thanks alot in advance.